# Passing arguments to constructor results in an error

Tags: c++, vector

I have a constructor which constructs a matrix, represented by a 2D vector, rows and columns number.

```
Matrix(const vector<vector<T> >* vect, const size_t rows, const size_t cols) :
matrix(&vect), matrixRows(rows), matrixCols(cols){}
```

I want to find the transpose of a matrix in one of my functions.

```
Matrix& trans() const
{
    vector<vector<T> > trans(matrixCols, vector<T>(matrixRows));
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < matrixRows; i++)
    {
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < matrixCols; j++)
        {
            trans[j][i] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    return Matrix(&trans, matrixCols, matrixRows);
}
```

The last line results in an error, because passing a vector this way is wrong.
What is the correct way?
Full error:

```
    Multiple markers at this line
    - invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Matrix<Complex>&' from an rvalue of type 
     'Matrix<Complex>'
    - required from 'Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::trans() const [with T = int]'
    - invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Matrix<double>&' from an rvalue of type 
     'Matrix<double>'
    - invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Matrix<int>&' from an rvalue of type 'Matrix<int>'
    - required from 'Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::trans() const [with T = Complex]'
    - required from 'Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::trans() const [with T = double]'
```

constructor error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - invalid conversion from 'const std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >**' to 'std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >::size_type 
     {aka long long unsigned int}' [-fpermissive]
    - candidate expects 3 arguments, 1 provided
    - no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >::vector(const std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > 
     >**)'
    - no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >' to 'const std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, 
     std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >*'
    - candidate: Matrix<T>::Matrix(const std::vector<std::vector<T> >*, size_t, size_t) [with T = double; size_t = long long unsigned int]
    - no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >' to 'const std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> 
     > > >*'
    - candidate: Matrix<T>::Matrix(const std::vector<std::vector<T> >*, size_t, size_t) [with T = int; size_t = long long unsigned int]
    - no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> >, std::allocator<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> > > >::vector(const std::vector<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> >, 
     std::allocator<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> > > >**)'
    - invalid conversion from 'const std::vector<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> >, std::allocator<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> > > >**' to 'std::vector<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> >, 
     std::allocator<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> > > >::size_type {aka long long unsigned int}' [-fpermissive]
    - no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >::vector(const std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, 
     std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >**)'
    - invalid conversion from 'const std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >**' to 'std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, 
     std::allocator<double> > > >::size_type {aka long long unsigned int}' [-fpermissive]
    - no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::vector<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> >, std::allocator<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> > > >' to 'const std::vector<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> >, 
     std::allocator<std::vector<Complex, std::allocator<Complex> > > >*'
    - candidate: Matrix<T>::Matrix(const std::vector<std::vector<T> >*, size_t, size_t) [with T = Complex; size_t = long long unsigned int]
```

Comment: So many problems. You store a pointer to a local variable (`trans`) and you return a reference to a temporary variable (`return Matrix(&trans, matrixCols, matrixRows);`. The latter one causes the compiler error. I imagine there are other errors lurking around.

Comment: I tried messing a lot with the &/*. I'm still stuck though.

Comment: I suggest learning about pointers and references instead of messing around with tokens `&` and `*`.

Comment: The `trans()` function is creating a new, local `Matrix` object in that `return` statement, and returning a ref to it, as the object is about to go out of scope.  My first suggestion would be to use `new` to create that matrix and change the `trans()` return type to `Matrix*`, so it persists.

Comment: The `Matrix` constructor probably needs work, too.  It receives a `std::vector<>` pointer, but passes the *address* of that pointer, or initializes a member with it.  The address is on the stack containing the pointer and will soon be meaningless.

Comment: One more suggestion:  I would not use the same name for the `trans()` function and for the local variable.  In some programming, function addresses are used as variables, and this naming could get very confusing.

Comment: I recommend passing the `vector` by reference.  Only use pointers as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you probably want the `Matrix` constructor to take the vector by reference instead of address:

```
Matrix(const vector<vector<T>>& vect, const size_t rows, const size_t cols)
 : matrix(vect), matrixRows(rows), matrixCols(cols)
{
}
```

(Note that this will cause the vector to be copied into `matrix`. Depending on the size of the vector, this might be fine - it really depends on the performance requirements of your program.)

Secondly, `trans()` should not return a reference to a `Matrix`. Since you are returning the value of a local, the variable will be destroyed when execution leaves the function, so the caller would have no way to make use of it.

Combined with the change to the `Matrix` constructor above, `trans()` should compile now:

```
Matrix trans() const
{
    vector<vector<T>> trans(matrixCols, vector<T>(matrixRows));
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < matrixRows; i++)
    {
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < matrixCols; j++)
        {
            trans[j][i] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    return Matrix(trans, matrixCols, matrixRows);
}
```